# How to get full Conky transparency in KDE 4.11?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, conky, transparency

On recent versions of KDE (4.10, 4.11 at least), the Conky window does not have a  transparent background, despite settings in the .conkyrc file.

Answer (score 1):

On my Kubuntu 13.10 installation, I got transparency working by doing 2 things:

1. appropriate settings in .conkyrc (see below)
2. Changing the compositing type from 'XRender' to 'OpenGL 3.1' in KDE System Settings > Desktop Effects > Advanced

The "magic" combination of options in my .conkyrc that work are:

```
own_window yes
own_window_title conky
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0
own_window_type normal
```

Note that as long as you use the argb options, you do NOT need to inlude `own_window_transparent`

if you include only `own_window_argb_visual` without `own_window_argb_value`,  then `own_window_transparent` functions as expected.